# load both image and video in a rails view using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

The problem is if I upload an Image it shows the image 2 times (one in the video_tag and the other in the `image_tag`

So I am trying to make the image only appear at the `image_tag`

```
<%= video_tag @post.file :controls =>true if @post.file? %>
<%= image_tag @post.file.url if @post.file? %>
```

Comment: video tag has poster attribute `video_tag @post.file, :controls =>true, poster: @post.file.url` put if statement outside of the video_tag. Docs: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_tag

Comment: sir the problem is that if I upload an image ONLY ... The post shows the same  image 2 times ... one due to image tag and the other due to video tag so how can i disable the video tag when an image is uploaded ?? and thanks

Comment: also the image tag displays the video image so i want to prevent this by only showing image tag if the file is an image and only show video tag if the file is a video ..

Comment: But you have the same file name `@post.file` how u know its video or image ?

Comment: thats one problem and whenever I try to apply a filter the method fails so hope you help and thanks

Comment: do you have any validation before uploading a file, like mp4, jpg or smth else?

Comment: there is a default validation in `file_uploader.rb ` which is `def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png mp4 mkv)
  end `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options to make it. Try first with rails helpers.

**Rails Version:**

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
    def file_type(filename)
       types = {
         :jpeg => "image",
         :jpg => "image",
         :gif => "image",
         :png => "image",
         :mp4 => "video", 
         :mkv => "video"
       }
       types[filename.split(".").last.to_sym]
    end
end

#html page
<% if @post.file? %>
     <% type = file_type(@post.file.url)%>
     <% if type == 'image' %>
         <%= image_tag @post.file.url %>
     <% elsif type == 'video' %>
         <%= video_tag @post.file :controls =>true %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Also, You can do it with javascript.**

```
#html page
#remove these lines
#<%= video_tag @post.file :controls =>true if @post.file? %>
#<%= image_tag @post.file.url if @post.file? %>

#add this div empty
<div id='dynamic_file_load'></div>


<script>
  types = {
    ".jpg": "image",
    ".jpeg": "image",
    ".gif": "image",
    ".png": "image",
    ".mp4": "video", 
    ".mkv": "video"
  }

  function checkeExtension(filename) {
      var re = /\..+$/;
      var ext = filename.match(re);
      if (types[ext] == 'video') {
         console.log("video")
         var el = document.createElement('video');
             el.src = 'filename';
         // make your own video player !!!
      } else {
         console.log("image")
         var el = document.createElement("IMG");
             el.setAttribute("src", filename);
             document.getElementById("res").appendChild(x);
      }
      document.getElementById("dynamic_file_load").appendChild(el);
  }
  checkeExtension("<%= @post.file.url %>");
</script>
```